# Data from Json manipulation in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, linegraph

I'm trying to draw a line graph using Angular JS and stuck on manipulating a json file.

I have aapl.json looks like:

```js
{
    "date":"2009-07-23",
    "numOfTweet":13,
    "oldScore":1,
    "newScore":0,
    "percentage1":-100,
    "appleClosePrice":21.27,
    "percentage2":0
  },
  {
    "date":"2009-07-24",
    "numOfTweet":32,
    "oldScore":2,
    "newScore":0,
    "percentage1":-100,
    "appleClosePrice":21.56,
    "percentage2":68.17113305
  },
```

and I have accessed this data from the json file in Javascript

```js
app.controller('LineCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('stock/aapl.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.series = ['Stock Market', 'Tweet Mood'];
      $scope.stocks = data;
  });
}]);
```

I can draw the two line graphs with this code in HTML. 
If `$scope.data = [[28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],[65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]];`

```html
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line chart-xl" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true"
click="onClick" series="series"></canvas>
```

My question is how to use 'percentage1' and 'percentage2' in the json as the data to draw line graphs.

Comment: Loop the data and construct data as per your needs, in this case for line graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a function that iterates over all of the JSON objects and pushes each of the percentages into arrays stored in $scope.data.
  I defined `$scope.data = [[], []];`

A function as follows should work:

```
  $scope.createGraphArray = function() {  
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.stocks.length; i++) {
      $scope.data[0].push($scope.stocks[i].percentage1)
      $scope.data[1].push($scope.stocks[i].percentage2)
    }
  }
```

Here is a Plunker that displays the arrays in $scope.data after it generates them from the JSON:

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ozRgsKD4W6hpSlIBN0Mg?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I added the code in my controller.js but it seems does not work. My code is in the third answer.

Answer (score 0):

The line commented works originally, but modified code as following tpie's doesn't show anything in the browser. Anything wrong?

```js
app.controller('LineCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('stock/aapl.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.selec = 'aapl'; //default as age
      $scope.series = ['Tweet Mood', 'Stock Market'];
      $scope.stocks = data;
      // $scope.labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
    
      $scope.labels = [];
      $scope.createLabels = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.stocks.length; i++) {
          $scope.labels.push($scope.stocks[i].date);
        }
      };  
      //   $scope.data = [
      //     [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      //     [28, 48, 40, 18, 86, 27, 90]
      //   ];
      $scope.data = [[], []];
      $scope.createGraphArray = function() {  
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.stocks.length; i++) {
          $scope.data[0].push($scope.stocks[i].percentage1);
          $scope.data[1].push($scope.stocks[i].percentage2);
        }
      };
    });
}]);
```

Comment: The code above has all the functions nested inside the success but you still have to call those functions.
So at the bottom you can put $scope.createGraphArray(); and $scope.createLabels();

Comment: in my plunker I call the function when I click the button, but you want to call them when there is success from the http call.

Comment: I can see your point that I need to call the function.  How do I call the function in canvas to draw a line graph?  <div class="panel-body" > <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line chart-xl" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true" click="onClick" series="series"></canvas> </div>

Comment: Well...that's a different question all together.  Canvas is just a container basically. You actually have to do all the drawing with JavaScript. Canvas can get a little involved depending on what you want to do, but there is lots out there on it. And you certainly don't need angular to draw on canvas. You can start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial.   You can also just google canvas tutorial.

Comment: I'm a newbie for AngularJS just trying it by myself. My question was I could access a controller with ng-controller and a sorting with ng-model,  you also accessed/called the function with ng-click. How do I call the function without/instead ng-click?

Comment: $scope.data = [[], []];       $scope.createGraphArray = function() {           for (var i = 0; i < $scope.stocks.length; i++) {           $scope.data[0].push($scope.stocks[i].percentage1);           $scope.data[1].push($scope.stocks[i].percentage2);         }       };  $scope.createGraphArray();

Comment: Oh, I can just call the function in the controller, thanks Genius :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
var data = [{
    "date":"2009-07-23",
    "numOfTweet":13,
    "oldScore":1,
    "newScore":0,
    "percentage1":-100,
    "appleClosePrice":21.27,
    "percentage2":0
  },
  {
    "date":"2009-07-24",
    "numOfTweet":32,
    "oldScore":2,
    "newScore":0,
    "percentage1":-100,
    "appleClosePrice":21.56,
    "percentage2":68.17113305
  }];

var percentage1 = [], percentage2 = [], output = [percentage1, percentage2];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    percentage1.push(data[i].percentage1);
    percentage2.push(data[i].percentage2);
}

alert(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Save the output to $scope.data and use it

Comment: @tpie I have not given code that will draw line graph. It is up to developer. I answered for "My question is how to use 'percentage1' and 'percentage2' in the json as the data to draw line graphs". Please read the question before you down vote

Comment: Instead of saying I don't believe it is going to work, rather I should say, I don't think the answer was very clear.

Comment: @tpie If you had seen my comment in the question, i hope it would have been clear. I have edited the answer and add what the developer needs to do with `output`